# efficient power exponent method in java(JDK 1.7)

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to create an optimum method for power(base,exponent) in java required for my project,where the types of both base and exponent is int,and exponent <= 10^9.However this has to be done in java?I know that bitshift can be used ,but it itself involves the usage of bitset in java.Kindly suggest an implementation

Comment: How do you want to deal with overflow?

Comment: Optimal is going to be very hard, but you can do `O(log exponent)` very easily: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring - not accounting for overflow, that is.

Comment: @IVlad: Note that the solution is `O(log exponent)` integer operations, and not `O(log exponent)` time/ops

Comment: i would have to accomodate the maximum limit of 10^9 ,however the base value always is 3 ,that is an advantage.I am not allowed for try catch exception handling for this particular code snippet

Comment: Why is it a problem to use bitset? Have you tried it to see how efficient it is? Also, have you tried other implementations such as `int` with bit-wise operations?

Comment: 3^(10^9) is going to overflow any native integer type. Are you sure you don't need the value modulo something?

Comment: hmm tried with bitwise ,had to convert int to bitset first ,newaz sorry forgot to mention the answer should be in modulo 1000000007

Comment: So you need a fast modular exponentiation algorithm. For example: [right-to-left binary method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method).

Comment: @Haile that looks like it should be an answer (with a little attributed paraphrasing from the Wikipedia page).

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `java.lang.BigInteger` class. It has a [pow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow%28int%29) method that does exactly what you want in a rather efficient way.

Comment: actually modpow() worked fine :) thanks guys solved the problem :)

Answer (score -1):

Since the exponent is in int, you already have the binary representation of the number (well the computer does). So you should have three integers, the base, the exponent and a temporary integer that you will use for computation and one more for solution. You start with this:

```
unsigned int base;//you manage input for this and exponent like you wish, probably passed in as parameters
unsigned int exponent;
unsigned int temp = base;
unsigned int answer = 1;
while (exponent!=0){
    if (exponent%2 == 1){
        answer *= temp;
    }
    exponent>>1;
        temp<<1;
}
```

Please try this algorithm and let me know how it works. The while look runs at max the bit length of the exponent (i.e. 32 times). This code doesn't handle large numbers or negative numbers, but I'm not sure if you require this or not.